# SQL BigQuery Distinct

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to get the sum of the amount failed of different people, I already have this query that I get the total values, ignoring the different people, but I need to make one where I only get the different ones.

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(case when (status = 'failed') then amount end) as failed
```

Comment: Try something like `SELECT person,SUM(...) AS failed FROM table GROUP BY person`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
SUM(case when (status != 'failed') then amount end) as failed
or
SELECT
SUM(case when (status  <> 'failed') then amount end) as failed